# Access Files on a Computer with Ubuntu when Windows Fails to Boot

Tags: 11.10

I have a question. I stumbled upon a very helpful life-hack in wikihow. (http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Files-on-a-Computer-With-Ubuntu-when-Windows-Fails-to-Boot)
It shows how you can retrieve your files when windows fails to boot using Ubuntu. According to the site, you must choose Ubuntu 11.10 to do the job. My question is will it work in any other versions of Ubuntu, or say other Linux distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with any version of Ubuntu or Linux as long as you can properly mount the filesystem. I've retrieved files from my windows 7 partition (NTFS) from Ubuntu 12.04.

These instructions would work from the terminal on a Linux machine:
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/mounting-a-windows-xp-ntfs-partition-in-linux/

Edit: To specifically answer your question, yes it will work with other versions of linux and all recent versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks @Salisburybs. The site was not clear of that. Well I was thinking of downloading both 11.10 and my favorite version. I guess I don't need to do that anymore.